# What do leafcutter ants do with the leaves?

Tags: ant

I have seen pictures of leafcutter ants carrying off leaves. What do they do with them? Make a house?

Comment: c'mon...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafcutter_ant maybe?

Comment: **Trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an underresearched trivia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafcutter_ant), these ants have a mutualistic relationship with a fungus. They feed their leaves to the fungus and in return the fungus makes pellets of food to feed it to the ant larvae. Along with that, the fungus provides defense to the ants.

Ants and many other animals cannot fully digest leaves as they contain cellulose which can only be digested by certain fungi and bacteria.

Comment: @AliceD I have added some extra information.